# get favicon from html (JSOUP)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

How can I get icon path from html string uses JSOUP?

I find to diferent way to add favicon on webpage -

(in Google)

first method I can to get uses doc.select("html head meta")

but I can't to select link tag

Comment: It is also possible that the favicon is not named in the HTML file. It is possible that the favicon is saved as `favicon.ico` on the web server (e.g. [on google](http://www.google.de/favicon.ico)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the file name on head element:

```
Connection con2=Jsoup.connect(url);
Document doc = con2.get();
Element e=doc.head().select("link[href~=.*\\.ico]").first();
String url=e.attr("href");
```

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Answer (score 3):

As Uwe Plonus pointed out in the comment you can always get the favicon from `<website>/favicon.ico`

[Google favicon](http://www.google.com/favicon.ico)

Comment: This is not always bot often the case. It's possible tht some web sites only use the meta tag...

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty late to submit a answer but
correct way to check is "rel" tag

```
 public boolean checkFevicon() {
        Elements e = doc.head().select("link[rel=shortcut icon]");
        if (e.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

jQuery equivalent

```
  $("link[rel='shortcut icon']")
```